# Difference between WIN32 memory macros vs cstring memory operations?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++

Memory block operations in c, such as memcpy, allow for optimised operations for moving or clearing blocks of memory. I have recently discovered that the WIN32 API provides macros supporting similar if not identical features, such as ZeroMemory.
I do not know the difference and wish to find out.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The oldest iterations of Windows predate C89. I would bet that most of those are probably backward-compatibility-with-Win16-or-perhaps-even-MSDOS aliases to the standard `<string.h>` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZeroMemory` is a macro that calls `memset`, `CopyMemory` is a macro that calls `memcpy`, etc. So, no difference at all.

Comment: since the macros call memset, memcpy, etc.. would that not make them less efficient than the operations in <string.h>?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. `ZeroMemory` is a macro so at compile time the pre-compiler will turn this into a direct call to the `memset` function. There is absolutely no difference in efficiency - it is the same function.